# Recursive call for handshaking party

Tags: java

currently, I'm doing a recursive assignment, where I need to count the number of handshakes between couples. In this party of N couples, only one gender (either male or female) can initiate shake hands with everyone. An example is like this:
[image]

This is my method of recursive so far and I'm really stuck here, can you guys help me with this

```
public int solve(int n){
        if(n==1){
            return 0;
        } else{
            return ((n*2)-2)+solve(n-1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will follow the diagram and assume that the women are the ones initiating handshakes.

Say we have N couples:

The female from the 1st couple will shake hands with every other female, resulting in N-1 shakes.
The female from the 1st couple will shake hands with every male that is not her own partner, resulting in N-1 shakes.
The male from the 1st couple will shake hands with every other female, resulting in N-1 shakes.
The male from the 1st couple will NOT shake hands with any of the males, since they cannot initiate handshakes.

So the total number of shakes that the first couple contributes is 3(N-1).
Then you can recurse on the next couple, passing in N-1 as the parameter, since the 1st couple's handshakes have already been counted.
And so on.

Resulting in:

```
public int solve(int n){
   if(n <= 1) return 0;
   return 3 * (n - 1) + solve(n-1);
}
```